# sybase - simple concatenation

Tags: string-concatenation, sap-ase

I am trying to create a utility stored proc, that can take a parameter and query a handy table for retrieving some quick info. For this I need to add '%' character before and after the param passed so as to use it in the query with `like`, as shown below.

Working code - if hardcoded

```
select some_field from TABLE where nm_field like ('%'+'abc'+'%')
```

But when I try to use the same with a variable, I get lesser results as compared to above query

```
declare @nm char(100)
select @nm = 'abc'
select some_field from TABLE where nm_field like ('%'+@abc+'%')
```

On some investigation, trial and error, the following select shows that '%' is added only before the param, and not at both sides.

```
declare @name char(20), @other char(20)
select @name = 'abc'
select @other = ('%' + @name + '%')
select @other
```

Expected Output

> %abc%

But actual output

> %abc

I am using Sybase ASE-12.5.4

Can you please help me out with what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change  `@nm` type to varchar as below

```
declare @nm varchar(100) 
select @nm = 'abc'
select some_field from TABLE where nm_field like ('%'+@abc+'%')
```

`Char` type has constant size and db fill a gap using spaces

```
declare @nm char(100) 
select @nm = 'abc'
```

below select

```
select @nm
```

will return abc and 97 spaces.

Comment: @mtk I added an explanation to my answer. As you said you can also use trim functions. For me better way is to use `varchar` type

Answer (score 0):

It seems, I have found the correct answer. It's the usage of `char` that is leading to this behaviour, since it is of fixed size. `varchar` isn't such and hence the concatenation works as expected.

With `char`, we need to add `trim` so that concatenation happens as expected

```
declare @str char(100)
select @str ='abc'
select ('%'+ltrim(rtrim(@str))+'%')
```

Output

```
%abc%
```